# Analyzing and understanding this algorithm

Tags: algorithm, mpi, social-networking, bigdata

I need to implement an algorithm found [here](http://staff.vbi.vt.edu/maleq/papers/sptriangle.pdf) (page 5) using data from [here](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/) (pick facebooks data, are only KB in size, if you wish to dig deeper). The algorithm is:

```
1: Ti ← 0 //Ti is pi’s count of triangles
2: for v ∈ Vi do
3:   for u ∈ Nv do
4:     if u ∈ Vi then
5:       S ← Nv ∩ Nu
6:       Ti ← Ti + |S| 
7:     else if u ∈ Vj then
8:       Send <data,Nv> to pj if not sent already
9:
10:  Check for incoming messages <t,X>:
11:  if t = data then
12:    Ti ← Ti+ SURROGATECOUNT(X, i)
13:  else
14:    Increment completion counter
15:
16: Broadcast <notifier,X> 
17: while completion counter < P-1 do
18:   Check for incoming messages <t,X>:
19:   if t = data then
20:     Ti ← Ti+ SURROGATECOUNT(X, i)
21:   else
22:     Increment completion counter
23:
24: MPIBARRIER
25: Find Sum T ← Pi Ti using MPIREDUCE
26: return T
```

As far as my understanding goes I need a two dimensional array. I need to query each element inside the `if` statement and do a +1 at `Ti` variable.

First question, `S ← Nv ∩ Nu` with what do I assign this variable `S`?
Wikipedia says: `A ∩ B means the set that contains all those elements that A and B have in common.`

Second question, if you take a look at the data, do I need all of them? I think I need just the `.edges` file.

Comment: That n looking character is the intersection and most programming languages have a Set class/object that provides that operation

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm not familiar with that class could you provide and example?

Comment: [`java.util.Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) and python [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
S ← Nv ∩ Nu
Ti ← Ti + |S|
```

Looks like you only need the number of elements that are in both `Nv` and `Nu`. So just count them an increase `Ti` by that number. The algorithm doesn't seem to use the `S` set for anything else.

It doesn't look like you need a lot of information about the connections, so just .edges could be enough.

Comment: So, if `Vi` is the first colum and `Nv` is the second in the array and I need to check if a number of `Nv` can also be found inside `Vi` what do i make of, for example that: http://imgur.com/qj2SDWH the number 3998 which is highlighted is in both sides. Do I add 1 for that at `Ti` ?

Comment: I'm not sure bhy you bring `Vi` here. You need `Nv` and `Nu`. But if  those are the columns then yes, you need to add one for 3998 and maybe more if there are other numbers that show up on both sides.

Comment: Thank you I'll start coding and return with more questions! :D